# How can out-of-tree sources be included in a Meson project?

Tags: embedded, build-system, meson-build

Some background: I am using Meson for an embedded C project. I have it working ([example](https://github.com/PyroAVR/k64_project_template)), but it isn't very clean.

The specific problem I would like to solve is including an **out-of-tree** Board Support Package (BSP) - a tree of headers and C files that act as initialization and abstraction code for a particular platform.

Previously I have been copying headers out of a vendor-provided BSP into my project on an as-needed basis, which does work, but there are disadvantages to doing this, the most important being the lack of reproducibility. Additionally, it causes duplication of code and makes it difficult to track where a particular bug came from if the bug is in the BSP.

The ways I have tried are:

1. Use an option in `meson_options.txt` to tell Meson where the BSP is on disk via `meson configure`. The issue with this method is that Meson throws an error during setup because options cannot be set until after setup is complete, and so it cannot find the requisite directories and refuses to continue.
2. Use a subproject and repeat the above - this causes the same issue.

I would ideally like the end-user to be able to set the BSP path with `meson configure`, instead of having to ever edit the build description (the whole point of Meson is to be user friendly!).

Is this possible? If it is not possible, why, and are there alternatives/common practice ways of doing this that I should know about?

Comment: I had a quick glance and the first thing I wondered why are you using some init.py script instead of putting this all into cross files?

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you state that

> options cannot be set until after setup is complete

That is not true. You can pass any option you want during the meson setup, using the following syntax:

```sh
$ meson <build dir> -D<option>=<value>
```

So I think the first way you tried to implement your option was correct, you just need to tell the user to set it directly during setup.